# asp.net in IronPython, speed execution of code, first time vs second time differences

Tags: asp.net, python, webforms, ironpython

I'm observing this behavior, when I run the same code for the second time with different parameters in webforms with IronPython,
it runs quite faster. I thought first this had to do with asp.net temporary files, but when I restart the server it gets slow for the first time
again. It's quite a code it has to run so it's reasonable, but it would be great if I could get the speed of the second exeucution. Now cPython compiled the files into pycs files for them to run faster, and I was wondering what does IronPython do to run faster
the code for the second time

is there anything I can do for the code to run at the speed execution of the second time, after I restart the server?

Greetings, Pablo

Comment: This is not the usual iis precompile slowness?

Comment: I dont know. We develop intranet software not massively accessed like websites, the only slowness I faced before in webforms with C# and VB.NET (when it wasnt related to the code itself) was related to the asp.net files not being yet compiled into temporary asp.net files for the first time.

Comment: "is there anything I can do for the code to run at the speed execution of the second time, after I restart the server?"  Yes.  Stop measuring the first execution.  Seriously.  The first of anything is always an outlier that's so much a special case that you **must** ignore it.  Why aren't you just ignoring it?

Comment: Because it bothers the users when we restart the server :)

Comment: So, on the server, add a scheduled task that runs at startup that requests a page from the application, thereby warming it up for the human users.

Comment: Not exactly the answer but useful workaround +1.

Answer (score 0):

I do not do a lot of work with .NET or IronPython, so this might be widely off the mark, but why not just [precompile](http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/precompiling-your-website-vb) your files using the [aspnet_compiler.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863.aspx) before you redeploy?

Comment: As far as I understand, you cant compile directly asp.net IronPython codefiles into assemblies. You can compile custom libraries into assemblies but aparently you cant codefiles, I think it's related asp.net for IronPython uses another compilation model. I've asked that question before here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916800/is-it-possible-to-associate-an-ironpython-asp-net-webform-to-a-dll-file